# Entity Framework join many to many

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, relational-database

I'm having some trouble 'converting' a T-SQL query to linq using Entity Framework v6.

My working T-SQL query looks like this:

```
SELECT 
    [Person].*, [Person_Firm_PersonResponsibility].*
FROM 
    [Person]
JOIN 
    [Person_Firm_PersonResponsibility] ON [Person].ID = [Person_Firm_PersonResponsibility].PersonID
WHERE 
    [Person_Firm_PersonResponsibility].FirmID = 389 
    AND [Person].ID = 330
```

In Linq I have the following:

```
using (var ctx = new MyContext())
{
    var result = (from p in ctx.People
                  join r in ctx.Person_Firm_PersonResponsibility on p.ID equals r.PersonID
                  where r.FirmID == firmId && p.ID == personId
                  select p)
                 .Include("Person_Firm_PersonResponsibility.PersonResponsibility")
                 .Include("Person_Firm_PersonResponsibility")
                 .FirstOrDefault();

    return result;
}
```

My goal is to only get a specific Person with responsibilities for a specific firm (firm ID) The relation between Firm, Person and Responsibilities is the many-to-many `Person_Firm_PersonResponsibility` table which I'm querying against.

The query 'works' in the sense that I get a the person, but it includes all of his/her responsibilities for any firm and not the specific firm (firmId) I've tried removing the .Include(""), but that didn't do it.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: did my answer solve your problem?

Comment: Sorry for the (way too long) delay, Steve :-( Yes, it did indeed solve my problem. Thanks a lot! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
from p in Persons
join r in  Person_Firm_PersonResponsibilities
    on p.ID equals r.PersonId
where (r.FirmId == 389 && p.ID == 330) 
select new {p, r}
```

Tested using LinqPad which shows the equivalent SQL as being:

```
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 Int = 389
DECLARE @p1 Int = 330
-- EndRegion
SELECT [t0].[ID], [t0].[Name], [t1].[FirmId], [t1].[PersonId]
FROM [Person] AS [t0]
INNER JOIN [Person_Firm_PersonResponsibility] AS [t1] ON ([t0].[ID]) = [t1].[PersonId]
WHERE ([t1].[FirmId] = @p0) AND ([t0].[ID] = @p1)
```